# Careers internal ad is cross user for favorite tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising, tag-watching

For a while now, the internal Careers advertisement is highlighting favorite tags, which is nice.

However, today I noticed it's "cross user", let me explain.

In my main account (this one), I have [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) as a favorite tag. When browsing SO, I see it highlighted in the Careers ads, which is OK. **However**, when browsing SO today with my [sock account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973864/shadow-of-the-shadow) I noticed:

> [image]

As you can see, [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) is highlighted, even though my sock account has no favorite tags.

The system should not perform this cross-user magic, e.g. shared computers - this will be total mess.

Favorite tags should be per-user, not per IP address or whatever mechanism is used now. (not cookies or local storage, as I browse each account with a different Chrome profile.)

Comment: If not C#, what kind of jobs is your sock account looking for?

Comment: @Cody something like [this](http://www.drapersjobs.com/job/2735771/technical-manager-socks/), I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't highlight favorite tags. We will highlight a tag if two conditions are met:

- It's one of the ten tags we currently highlight (c#, java, python, android, c++, ios, linux, node.js, php, and ruby-on-rails).
- The tag is one of your five most-viewed tags out of the tags we track for prediction purposes.

So, both of your users undoubtedly have viewed enough C# questions, in comparison with other tags, for it to be highlighting. You can verify this by [downloading your "prediction data" here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data).

Comment: Huh, now I feel stupid-ish for not checking it deeper, e.g. javascript tag not highlighted even though it's favorite. Thanks a bunch! :)